# Map activity not shown the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to do two map activities in different time in two ways
01.show two locations (assume current user's location and end location) on a map.
02.show few locations (user's current location & few selected locations) on a map. on both these occasions locations are taken from another activity using a intent.it include string array when it use in second way.
How ever both time i got an error saying

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions."

I tried to solve this issue several times but i couldn't. If somebody can help me,it will become huge relief for my final year project.My coding are as follows.

Activity for first method

```
package com.ksfr.sdfinder;

public class DistanceFinderMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

//codes
public void FindDistanceButtonClicked (View view){
    Data_Select();
    if (selectedview=="text"){
        distance_cur_to_end_DF=cur_Location.distanceTo(end_Location)/1000;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        Str_distance=String.valueOf(df.format(distance_cur_to_end_DF));
        Intent DFTxtIntent =new Intent(DistanceFinderMainActivity.this,DistanceFinderTextActivity.class);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("provider",Provider);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("accuracy",Str_accuracy);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("schoolName",Str_SchName);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("schoolAddress",Str_SchAddress);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("schoolType",StrType);
        DFTxtIntent.putExtra("DFDistance",Str_distance);

        startActivity(DFTxtIntent);
    }
    if (selectedview=="map"){
        Intent DFMapIntent = new Intent(DistanceFinderMainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("source",2);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("DFcur_latitude",cur_latitude);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("DFcur_longitude",cur_longitude);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("DFend_latitude",end_latitude);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("DFend_longitude",end_longitude);
        DFMapIntent.putExtra("schoolName",Str_SchName);

        startActivity(DFMapIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Activity for second method

```
public class SchoolSelectorMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
//codes

if(selectedview=="map"){
        if (listCount!=0){
            Intent SSMapIntent =new Intent(SchoolSelectorMainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            SSMapIntent.putExtra("maxDistance",Str_maxdistance);
            SSMapIntent.putExtra("source", 1);
            SSMapIntent.putExtra("listCount", listCount);
            if(listCount!=0){
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("nameList",nameListIntent);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("typeList", typeListIntent);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("distanceList",distanceListIntent);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("latitude",latListIntent);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("longitude", lngListIntent);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("cur_lat",cur_latitude);
                SSMapIntent.putExtra("cur_lng", cur_longitude);
            }
            startActivity(SSMapIntent);
       }
    }
}
```

My mapactivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
//codes
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    source=bundle.getInt("source");
    maxDistance=bundle.getDouble("maxDistance");
    if (source==1){
        listCount=bundle.getInt("listCount");
        cur_lat=bundle.getDouble("cur_lat");
        cur_lng=bundle.getDouble("cur_lng");

        if (listCount!=0) {
            String[] nameListMap = bundle.getStringArray("nameList");
            String[] typeListMap = bundle.getStringArray("typeList");
            String[] distanceListMap= bundle.getStringArray("distanceList");
            double [] latListMap=bundle.getDoubleArray("latitude");
            double [] lngListMap=bundle.getDoubleArray("longitude");

            try{
                for (int l =0;l<listCount;l++)
                {
                    selectedListMap[l][0]=nameListMap[l];
                    selectedListMap[l][1]=typeListMap[l];
                    selectedListMap[l][2]=distanceListMap[l];
                    selectedListMap[l][3]=String.valueOf(latListMap[l]);
                    selectedListMap[l][4]=String.valueOf(lngListMap[l]);
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Null pointer catched",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
               }
    if (source==2){
        cur_lat=bundle.getDouble("DFcur_latitude");
        cur_lng=bundle.getDouble("DFcur_longitude");
        cur_latLngDF =new LatLng(cur_lat,cur_lng);
        end_lat=bundle.getDouble("DFend_latitude");
        end_lng=bundle.getDouble("DFend_longitude");
        end_latLngDF=new LatLng(end_lat,end_lng);
        schName=bundle.getString("schoolName");
    }
}
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Marker[] end_marker=new Marker[listCount];
    LatLng[] end_latLng=new LatLng[listCount];

    switch (source){
        case 1:
            for (int l =0;l<listCount;l++)
            {
                end_latLng[l]=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(selectedListMap[l][3]) ,Double.parseDouble(selectedListMap[l][4]));
                end_marker[l] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(end_latLng[l])
                        .title(selectedListMap[l][0])
                        .snippet("Distance :" + selectedListMap[l][2] + " km."));

            }
            cur_latLngSS=new LatLng(cur_lat,cur_lng);

            cur_Marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(cur_latLngSS)
                    .title("User Location")
                    .snippet("User's Location Here."+cur_latLngSS)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

            for (int l=0;l<listCount;l++){
                builder1.include(end_latLng[l]);
                end_marker[l].showInfoWindow();
            }
            builder1.include(cur_latLngSS);
            cur_Marker.showInfoWindow();
            LatLngBounds bounds1 = builder1.build();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds1, 100));
            break;
        case 2:
            builder1.include(cur_latLngDF);
            builder1.include(end_latLngDF);
            cur_MarkerDF = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(cur_latLngDF)
                    .title("User Location")
                    .snippet("User's Location Here."+cur_latLngDF)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            end_MarkerDF = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(end_latLngDF)
                    .title(schName)
                    .snippet("Distance from user's location:"+distance+"km")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            cur_MarkerDF.showInfoWindow();
            end_MarkerDF.showInfoWindow();
            LatLngBounds bounds2 = builder1.build();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds2, 20));
            break;

    }


}
```

error log

```
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ksfr.sdfinder, PID: 7720
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.a.a.ae.b(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.dy.a(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:83)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ksfr.sdfinder.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:166)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.be.a(SourceFile:82)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.fb.run(Unknown Source)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
01-06 14:20:37.922 7720-7720/com.ksfr.sdfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in my maps activity I defined a LatLngBounds.Builder globally as follows                LatLngBounds.Builder builder1 = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my coding is camera update method.Instant of that one I used following coding and it worked for me.

```
private static final double PADDING_PERCENTAGE = 0.12;// offset from edges of the map 12% of screen
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //codes
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int padding = (int) (width * PADDING_PERCENTAGE);

    CameraUpdate cu1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds1, width, height, padding);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu1);
}
```